# Ipad jquery smooth scrolling animations?

Tags: jquery, ipad

Im making a site with a smooth scrolling animation using this plug in: 
http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

It looks great on my computer but quite jerky on an ipad. Is this just a limitation of ipads or is there a different method that could have smoother results?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the best way to achieve smooth animations is via css animations. It runs really fast and is hardware accelerated. Works really great on mobile devices, such as the iphone or ipad.

Here is a good article/tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_transitions, but just search on it on google, there's plenty of information. Also I can recommend Dan Cederholms book [CSS3 for web designers](http://www.abookapart.com/products/css3-for-web-designers).